# Angular 6 ng build --prod error "ERROR Error: ngIfElse must be a TemplateRef, but received 'true'."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

ERROR Error: ngIfElse must be a TemplateRef, but received 'true'

HTML File

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected value="0">Select Manufacturer</option>
  <option *ngFor="let brand of allMakes">
     {{ brand.brand }}
  </option>
</select>
```

ts file

```js
this.allMakes = [{
  id: '1',
  brand: 'Mazda'
},
{
  id: '2',
  brand: 'Audi',
}];
```

It all started right after i upgraded from Angular 5 to Angular 6

Console Log Error

```
ERROR Error: ngIfElse must be a TemplateRef, but received 'true'.
  at Vt (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at t.set [as ngIfElse] (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at Sa (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1
  at main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1
  at es (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at Os (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at Object.updateDirectives 
  (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at Object.updateDirectives (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
  at ts (main.6e360f04b7d39ee1dc33.bundle.js:1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the error?

Comment: There is no `ngIf` in there, please post all the code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issues solved, the cause was a redundant property(Bool) that was attached to the "ng-template"

```
noData: boolean = true;
<ng-template #noData>...Blah blah...</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 49):

For `ngIf` with else block you need to use `<ng-template>` block as a else in your `.html` file.

Here is the sample code:

`<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>`

Comment: I was using `<ng-container>` in my code for the else block. Changing it to `<ng-template>` fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no error found while build using --prod option with your code.
I've created a editor for you to playaround with your issue, if any. I've copied your code and its working fine.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4ctul

or try changing this line of code with below one.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { enableLegacyTemplate: true })
```

If you are still getting issue, just edit and save your code on above url. I will take a look.