# Angular 12 - *ngIf;Then;Else - must be a TemplateRef, but received '[object HTMLInputElement]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After migrating Angular 6.x to Angular 12.x, I'm facing template related issues.

***UPDATED***

I've my code like this

```
    <table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input #selectAll type="checkbox" [checked]="myFunctionName()" (click)="toggleSelection()"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <span *ngIf="myFunctionName(); then removeAll ; else selectAll"></span>
      <ng-template #selectAll>{{SELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
      <ng-template #removeAll>{{DESELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Below error i got

> ERROR Error: ngIfElse must be a TemplateRef, but received '[object
> HTMLInputElement]'

What i tried?

```
<table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input #selectAll type="checkbox" [checked]="myFunctionName()" (click)="toggleSelection()"
          />
        </th>
        <th>
          <ng-container *ngIf="myFunctionName(); then removeAll ; else selectAll"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #selectAll>{{SELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
          <ng-template #removeAll>{{DESELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**ts**

```
@ViewChild('selectAll' , {static: true}) selectAll!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
    myFunctionName(): boolean {
      if (this.checkboxes) {
        // other stufs
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Could someone help me how to can refactor pieces ?

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Can you make an example on stackblitz?

Comment: I tried creating stackbliz, but due to some reason, firewalls blocking stackblitz and not able to access other angular online sandboxes

Comment: missing semicolon before `else`

Comment: @ChrisG not working i changed as you said

Comment: Check this, if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820518/angular-6-ng-build-prod-error-error-error-ngifelse-must-be-a-templateref-bu

Comment: @AviadP. already changed but no luck

Comment: @Tushar sadly that solution is not working for my scenario :(

Comment: idk if it makes any difference, but could you add a semicolon like this: `myFunctionName(); then removeAll; else selectAll` and have you checked in your code if there is another variable called `selectAll`?

Comment: @Zerotwelve yes i do have selectAll like `@ViewChild('selectAll' , {static: true}) selectAll!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmeg4s?file=src/app/app.component.html - works. try to break it.

Comment: @AviadP. Am accessing stackblitz in mobile... i exactly replicate what you said in there. but still am getting same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem is very simple, you have #selectAll twice in your HTML code.
to fix this you need to rename one of them

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myFunctionName(); then removeAllBlock; else selectAllBlock"></ng-container>
<ng-template #selectAllBlock>{{SELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #removeAllBlock>{{DESELECT_ALL}}</ng-template>
```

and if you use the `selectAll` input only in your function, you don't need the @ViewChild but you can do it like this:
(just an improvement, not mandatory)

```html
 <input #myInput type="checkbox" [checked]="myFunctionName()" (click)="toggleSelection(myInput)"/>
```

```js
toggleSelection(myInput:HTMLInputElement){
// do stuff with your input
}
```

Comment: Awesome man. Good catch.. error disappeared .. I didn't realize that. Thank you so much

Comment: if we use <ng-template> , onclick of any icon ,  index value not getting in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your error:

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <ng-container *ngIf="myFunctionName(); else selectAll">
          {{someEslePartWillComeHere}}
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #selectAll>{{someThenableContentGoesHere}}</ng-template>
      </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `ngIf` directive should wrapper the content that you want to show when condition is `true`.

Comment: I've updated my question properly.. pls check

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, except the template reference variable used in ng-template. For example: there should not be any properties in your class as in the same name as #selectAll and #removeAll references

```
<ng-template #selectAll>{{someThenableContentGoesHere}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #removeAll>{{someEslePartWillComeHere}}</ng-template>
```

Comment: I've updated my question properly.. pls check